# No provider for NavController

Tags: angular, navigation, ionic2

i started an ionic 2 app from the sidemenu starter. Now i want to move the code generated into the app component (the menu) into a folder and write a home component instead. When i run the app it shows me this error:

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for NavController!

The code for my app.component is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';

import { Login } from '../pages/login/login';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  nav: NavController;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, nav: NavController) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }

  registerUserWithFacebook(){
    console.log('Facebook');
    //this.nav.setRoot(pantryList);
  }

  registerUserWithGoogle() {
    console.log('Google');
    //this.nav.setRoot(pantryList);
  }

  openSignUpPage(){
    console.log('Signup');
    //this.nav.setRoot(Signup);
  }

  openLoginPage(){
    console.log('Login');
    this.nav.push(Login);
  }

  openTermsOfService(){
    console.log('Terms of service');
  }
}
```

And i want to redirect to my menu (sidemenu) page:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { pantryList } from '../pantryList/pantryList';

@Component({
    templateUrl: "login.html"
})
export class Login {

    email: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    }

   onLogin() {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(pantryList);
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by a workaround. I was reading and i found [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/why-cant-i-import-navcontroller-and-viewcontroller-into-service-or-app/40999) post asking sometinhg similiar.

So i just change my app.html into this:

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

And my app.component into this:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild('content') nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = Home;
  ...
}
```

Now when i redirect in my home page i dont have any problems.

Comment: self answer, Good :)

Comment: thanks :) hard work to find this work around but im happy now

Comment: NavController is only a child class of Nav. You indeed need to ViewChild your Nav into app.component.ts and fro there you can pass it through to another component to handle your navigation there. Beware of cyclic dependencies as always.

Answer (score 5):

Forced that thing to work in next way

```
  constructor(
    protected app: App
  ) {

...

  get navCtrl(): NavController {
    return this.app.getActiveNav();
  }
```

Comment: To answer the initial question, you can ignore the navCtrl function and use: `onLogin() { this.app.getActiveNav().setRoot(pantryList); }`. `App` is imported from `ionic-angular`.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution works. Apart, In case if you run into the same as me, please check the below.

I got the same error when I accidentally added `NavController` in the Injectable `Provider` file.

```
@Injectable()
export class UtilsProvider {

  constructor(
    private toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public navCtrl: NavController // *** Make sure to remove this line from Providers***
  ) {
    console.log("Hello UtilsProvider");
    if (!this.isDev) console.log("Productions build");
  }
}
```